# Azure CosmosDB MongoAPI - Cursor during skip/take is dead after 300 results?

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

After porting some of our Nodejs running processes to use Azure's CosmosDB MongoAPI instead of MLab's DB hosting I have had nothing but problems. The real show-stopper I encountered was a dead cursor when I try to page through a fairly large resultset.

```
SteamGameModel.find()
    .skip(300)
    .take(250)
    .exec(function(err, results){...});
```

I can successfully fetch the first 250-300 documents, but after I skip beyond this I get the following:

`cursor does not exist, was killed or timed out.`

I found a [post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/7862be04-2396-4679-a5be-72acded1ad16/mongoerror-cursor-does-not-exist-was-killed-or-timed-out?forum=azurecosmosdb) stating cursors are not enabled?!?!?, and a request has to be made to a "dead" email address `askdocdb@microsoft.com` to enable them, which I tried.

Is this really the case, that cursors are not enabled or am I missing something? As I can't seem to find any documentation confirming this.

Comment: *"..  found a post on MSDN stating cursors are not enabled ..."* - Just because someone wrote something, does not make it correct. Where are you getting `.take()` from? That's not a thing in the mongoose or MongoDB API. Pretty sure you mean `limit()`. The only real truth is is `CosmosDB !== MongoDB`. So ultimately if you want to use ComosDB, then use its "own **native**" API. If you want the MongoDB API, then use an actual MongoDB server. These "compatibility" claims never work out to be totally true.

Comment: Either way, "skipping" is not really efficient, and you really should be looking for "greater than" a last result.

Comment: I agree with you Neil, however, Cosmos supplies a Mongo wrapper and that is what I am using it for vs. using their CosmosDB API. CosmosDB doesn't understand the concept of collections just as one example. I am not a fan of Cosmos but it has more throughput than MLab comparing cost for cost. Hence why we are spiking it out to see if it is an alternative.

Comment: Well it's just **not MongoDB** ( not even "technically" a "wrapper", but not getting into that ). Just don't expect things to work, or there to be solutions when they don't. Really trying to stay away from editorial content here, but there are in fact a lot of issues that even make that hard. You should focus on things that are "supported to work" is all I'm going to say.